# Can't insert null value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have problem with Oracle Apex 21 he give me error Ora 01400. I can't find when this code obtain  null value. In sqldeveloper without 'insert' all work fine. But in Oracle Apex he  wan't  work. Probably I wrote something wrong. Thaks for understanding and helping.

```
desc pipiki 
id NUMBER  no NULL,
tp1 VARCHAR2(512) not NULL,
col3 date,
col4 date,
col5 number,
col6 number

desc cc
id number not NULL
col1 varchar2 not NULL
col2 varchar2 not NULL
col3 varchar2 
col4 varchar2 not NULL
col5 DATE
col6 DATE
col7 number
col8 number
col9 number
col10 number

declare
     l_cur_1 varchar2(255);
     l_cur_2 varchar2(255) := :val2;
     l_np1 varchar2(255) := :val3;
     l_np2 varchar2(255) := :val4;
     l_ai NUMBER;
     l_ui NUMBER;
     tp1 VARCHAR2(512);
     tp2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    l_ai := gui /* <- function */;
    select uu into l_cur_1 
    from cc 
    where upper(uu) = upper(v('APP_USER'))
    group by uu;
    l_ui := uuu /* <- function */;
    if(l_ui <= '0') THEN
        tp1 := 0;
    else 
        tp1 := rpipi(l_cur_1,l_cur_2);
        UPDATE pipiki 
        set col = '0'
        where pic = tp1;
        commit;
        tp1 := 0;
        tp1 := rpipi(l_cur_1,l_np1);
        if(tp1 <= '0')THEN
            tp1 := 0;
        ELSE
            insert into pipiki(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
            values(tp1,SYSDATE,sysdate,l_ui,'0');
            commit;
        end if;
    end if;
    select ii into tp2 from pipiki where rsa = tp1;
    update cc
    set pig10 = tp2
    where upper(rsos) = upper(l_cur_1);
    commit;
end;
```

Comment: You can add `dbms_output.put_line` and do very simple debugging by yourself. What stops you doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post tables' descriptions, so we can't know which columns are declared as `NOT NULL`.

Candidates are:

- table `pipiki`:

  - `col1` (you're inserting `tp1` into it)

    - `tp1` gets its value from `rpipi` function - check what it returns for passed parameters
  - `col4` (you're inserting `l_ui`)

    - `l_ui` gets its value from `uuu` function (it doesn't accept any parameters so I *presume* it is OK)
- table `cc`

  - `pig10` (you're updating it with `tp2`)

    - `tp2` is returned from the `pig` table's `ii` column; as that query didn't fail with `no_data_found`, I presume it got its value

As you're running it in Apex, **enable debug** mode, run the page and - once it fails - check debug info.

Comment: I'm changed code. All function return one value, without errors.

Comment: Well, something is missing, otherwise Oracle wouldn't raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

To check the values of variables in a pl/sql process in the apex session, use the API `apex_debug`. Add a call to apex_debug in pl/sql block, enable debug and look for the results of the call in the the debug data. Example:

```
declare
     l_cur_1 varchar2(255);
< rest of your code>
        ELSE
          apex_debug.info(
            p_message => 'Before pipiki insert: col1: %0, l_ui: %1',
            p0 => tp1,
            p1 => l_ui);
          insert into pipiki(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
            values(tp1,SYSDATE,sysdate,l_ui,'0');
< rest of your code>
```

Run the page process in debug and look for the string "Before pipiki insert". That will show you the values of tp1 and l_ui.

Add more calls to apex_debug to do more debugging if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, column ID is not null, but I don't see it in the column list of INSERT statement. That's why you saw ORA-01400.

To prevent ORA-01400, you have 3 options:

1. Provide a value for NOT NULL column in INSERT list.
2. Remove NOT NULL from the column.
3. Provide a default value for NOT NULL columns.

https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-ora-01400-cannot-insert-null-into/

In my opinion, it's basically about the concept of NOT NULL. It's irrelavant to APEX or any newer releases.